# Какой есть аналог ret в ARM32 ассемблере?

Tags: linux, c, функции, ассемблер, arm

В отличие от arm64, в armhf нету инструкции `ret`, чтобы вернуться из функции. Да вот проблема: я не нашёл рабочего кода для возвращения из функции. Я пробовал [отсюда](https://quantum5.ca/2017/10/19/arm-ways-to-return/), но ничего не помогло.

Код C:

```
extern void asmfunc();
int main() {
    asmfunc();
    return 0;
}
```

Код ASM:

```
.data
tekst:
    .string "It works!"
    len = .-tekst                                                                         
.text
.global asmfunc
asmfunc:
    push        {r3, r4, lr}
    mov r0, #1
    ldr r1, =tekst
    ldr r2, =len
    mov r7, #64
    swi 0
    pop         {r3, r4, pc}
```

Makefile:

```
all:
    @arm-linux-gnueabi-as asm.S -o asm.o
    @arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -c code.c -o code.o
    @arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc code.o asm.o -o run
```

```
 /tmp # ./run
bash: /tmp/run: No such file or directory # [с правами все ок]
```

Comment: Смотрите внимательно -- в начале `push        {r3, r4, lr}` (`lr` это link register, в него при call заносится адрес следующей инструкции), а в конце `pop         {r3, r4, pc}` (`pc` это programm counter, т.е. адрес инструкции, которую надо выполнить). / Всякие там programmer reference у ARM-а вы принципиально не читаете? -)

Comment: дык, а `make`, то кто будет делать? в остальном всё вроде-как-так, но регистры не те сохраняешь и системный вызов не тот...

Comment: чёрт его знает, я пробовал все методы по ссылке. Там и `bx, lr`, `mov pc, lr`. У меня ничего из этого не работает

Comment: Fat-Zer, с системным вызовом все нормально: ```#define __NR_write 64```

Comment: А ldd есть в целевой системе ? Надо посмотреть с чем слинкована в итоге программа и есть ли эти библиотеки на целевой системе. (т.е. запустить ldd /tmp/run на целевой системе) Для теста так же можно слинковать файл статикой

Comment: @RandomDice779, `__NR_write 64` — это на aarch64... на простом arm'е `write()` должен быть `4`-м...

Comment: не помогает, дело явно в функции возврата

Comment: @RandomDice779, почему ты считаешь, что «дело в функции возврата», когда по тем данным, которые ты привёл, исполняемый файл у тебя даже не запускается?